# Is there a way to perfectly calculate the difference in radius between an outer rectangle and an inner rectangle?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Okay, so I have this function:

```
function roundedRect(x,y,w,h,r1,r2,r3,r4){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + r1,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w - r2,y);
    ctx.arcTo(x + w,y,x + w,y + r2,r2);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w,y + h - r3);
    ctx.arcTo(x + w,y + h,x + w - r3,y + h,r3);
    ctx.lineTo(x + r4,y + h);
    ctx.arcTo(x,y + h,x,y + h - r4,r4);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y + r1);
    ctx.arcTo(x,y,x + r1,y,r1);
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

This draws a rectangle with arced edges according to values for radii. Here's how it looks in action:

```html
<canvas id = "c" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>

<script>
    let ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
    function roundedRect(ctx,x,y,w,h,r1,r2,r3,r4){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + r1,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w - r2,y);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y,x + w,y + r2,r2);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w,y + h - r3);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y + h,x + w - r3,y + h,r3);
        ctx.lineTo(x + r4,y + h);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y + h,x,y + h - r4,r4);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y + r1);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y,x + r1,y,r1);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    roundedRect(ctx,5,5,90,90,10,10,10,30);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
</script>
```

Now, let's say I wanted to render one of these rectangles inside the other. The first render is *only* the stroke, and the second render is *only* the fill. This looks like so:

```html
<canvas id = "c" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>

<script>
    let ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
    function roundedRect(ctx,x,y,w,h,r1,r2,r3,r4){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + r1,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w - r2,y);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y,x + w,y + r2,r2);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w,y + h - r3);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y + h,x + w - r3,y + h,r3);
        ctx.lineTo(x + r4,y + h);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y + h,x,y + h - r4,r4);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y + r1);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y,x + r1,y,r1);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    roundedRect(ctx,5,5,90,90,10,10,10,30);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    roundedRect(ctx,5,5,90,90,10,10,10,30);
    ctx.fill();
</script>
```

Everything's looking great so far. But it's *not* good so far. If I reduce the transparency of the render then you can see a very ugly issue:

```html
<canvas id = "c" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>

<script>
    let ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
    function roundedRect(ctx,x,y,w,h,r1,r2,r3,r4){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + r1,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w - r2,y);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y,x + w,y + r2,r2);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w,y + h - r3);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y + h,x + w - r3,y + h,r3);
        ctx.lineTo(x + r4,y + h);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y + h,x,y + h - r4,r4);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y + r1);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y,x + r1,y,r1);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    roundedRect(ctx,5,5,90,90,10,10,10,30);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    roundedRect(ctx,5,5,90,90,10,10,10,30);
    ctx.fill();
</script>
```

You can see that the edges of the fill overlap the stroke, and it causes a very ugly effect. The obvious solution is to scoot the fill in a bit (increase its x and y by half the stroke width, decrease its width and height by full stroke width) but that causes there to be an ugly, unwanted gap in each corner as can be seen below:

```html
<canvas id = "c" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>

<script>
    let ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
    function roundedRect(ctx,x,y,w,h,r1,r2,r3,r4){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + r1,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w - r2,y);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y,x + w,y + r2,r2);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w,y + h - r3);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y + h,x + w - r3,y + h,r3);
        ctx.lineTo(x + r4,y + h);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y + h,x,y + h - r4,r4);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y + r1);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y,x + r1,y,r1);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    roundedRect(ctx,5,5,90,90,10,10,10,30);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    roundedRect(ctx,10,10,80,80,10,10,10,30);
    ctx.fill();
</script>
```

A fix for this would be to simply calculate a new radius for each corner. This absolutely works so long as it's done right. I found that multiplying by 0.666 seems to yield a *very* close result most of the time, and it's what I've been using up until now. But, as can be seen below, it's far from perfect and its imperfections only grow stronger with larger radii.

```html
<canvas id = "c" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>

<script>
    let ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
    function roundedRect(ctx,x,y,w,h,r1,r2,r3,r4){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + r1,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w - r2,y);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y,x + w,y + r2,r2);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w,y + h - r3);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y + h,x + w - r3,y + h,r3);
        ctx.lineTo(x + r4,y + h);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y + h,x,y + h - r4,r4);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y + r1);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y,x + r1,y,r1);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    roundedRect(ctx,5,5,90,90,10,10,10,30);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    roundedRect(ctx,10,10,80,80,10 * 0.666,10  * 0.666,10 * 0.666,30 * 0.666);
    ctx.fill();
</script>
```

So now finally onto my question... Is there any means of perfectly calculating this new radius? Is there some magic number to multiply by which will always yield 100% perfect results? Is it a lot harder than I expect? In my final result, I want a way to make these two rectangles line up perfectly no matter the radius.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I spent about an hour or so just aimlessly messing around with these values, and I accidentally came across a perfect solution. The value for the border radius of the inner rectangle is: `outerRectangleRadius - outerRectangleStrokeWidth / 2`

So far this has worked perfectly for anything that I can throw at it and I'm very pleased! :) I hope that this question + answer really helps a lot of people in the future.

```html
<canvas id = "c" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>

<script>
    let ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
    function roundedRect(ctx,x,y,w,h,r1,r2,r3,r4){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + r1,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w - r2,y);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y,x + w,y + r2,r2);
        ctx.lineTo(x + w,y + h - r3);
        ctx.arcTo(x + w,y + h,x + w - r3,y + h,r3);
        ctx.lineTo(x + r4,y + h);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y + h,x,y + h - r4,r4);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y + r1);
        ctx.arcTo(x,y,x + r1,y,r1);
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

    const strokeWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
    
    const radii = [10,40,20,30];

    // draw outer square
    roundedRect(ctx,5,5,90,90,radii[0],radii[1],radii[2],radii[3]);
    ctx.stroke();
    // draw inner square
    ctx.beginPath();
    
    roundedRect(ctx,5 + strokeWidth / 2,5  + strokeWidth / 2,90 - strokeWidth,90 - strokeWidth,radii[0] - strokeWidth / 2,radii[1] - strokeWidth / 2,radii[2] - strokeWidth / 2,radii[3] - strokeWidth / 2);
    ctx.fill();
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe there's some misunderstanding in the air. I did it with all good intention, though I made mistake at first take, regretfully, in my own answer which I deleted. But I didn't post a wrong snippet to your answer, I posted the **revised version**, you can check the edit history to verify.

Comment: I love your solution and want to add a snippet to illustrate the idea, that's my whole point. Man, I'm not sure in what way this gesture upsets you, but your comment surely upsets me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no intentions of upsetting you. It just seemed a bit odd to me that your answer collected 3 downvotes because it was wrong, so I posted a comment on it saying that it was inaccurate and why, and then I get a notification saying that my post was edited and I open it to realize that my answer has been edited to reflect the answer that I just explained was inaccurate. But if you were just intending to be helpful then I don't mind. I'm sorry that I came off a bit harsh. I appreciate you trying to help, and I appreciate your desire to improve my answer. Thanks. :)